# Sudden Increase in Reputation

Tags: support, reputation

In **Arqade**, yesterday my reputation was like 192-195 but today it suddenly increased to 309. I don't know what happened. Is there a lucky draw or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got the association bonus of 100 rep. You get it once on every stack website out there once you reach 200 rep (example: You reached 200rep on Arqade, you got 100 rep here and every other stack website, if you create an account on other stack websites, you'll get 100 rep on them too).

[Here is your rep page, you can see it here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/139312/demize?tab=reputation).

Comment: So that means if i am not on STACK OVERFLOW, i will never get the association bonus there now?

Comment: @DeMize nope, you'll get it once you create an account there.

Comment: @Demize - it's applied every time you sign up for another Stack Exchange account

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks for telling that.

Comment: @DeMize The purpose of the association bonus is to get you past new user restrictions on other SE sites. It woudn't be much use if you didn't get it when you create a new account :)